# Stop AnimatedVectorDrawable animation after playing

Tags: android, animation, vector, android-vectordrawable, animatedvectordrawable

I have an AnimatedVectorDrawable that animates from play to pause state when clicked.

```
...
 animatedVectorDrawable.registerAnimationCallback(new Animatable2.AnimationCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Drawable drawable) {
                      //Reset the image back to its original state

                      //What I've tried so far
                      /* img.setImageResource(R.drawable.original_state)
                        animatedVectorDrawable.stop()
                        animatedVectorDrawable.reset() */
                    }
                });
 animatedVectorDrawable.start();
```

However, I've not been able to successfully get it back to its original state so that I can play it back again. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
    final Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    animatedVector.registerAnimationCallback(new Animatable2.AnimationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(final Drawable drawable) {
            mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    animatedVectorDrawable.start();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    animatedVectorDrawable.start();
```

Comment: well this keeps it looping back and forth

Comment: @user8284066 you could define a boolean variable and start anim only when the variable equals to true.

Answer (score -3):

To get the initial state of the drawable use `animatedVectorDrawable.seekTo(0)` and the you can call `animatedVectorDrawable.stop()`

Comment: .seekTo() is not a function